# passing file to another view

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to make an application where one can upload a file, then make some modifications to its content and afterwards download it. The problem i have encountered is:

Models:

```
class Subtitles(models.Model):

file = models.FileField()
line_A = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
line_B = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
line_C = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

first view is supposed recieve the uploaded file via form and initialise an Subtitles object with it, then it should pass this object to second view where it would get the line_A, line_B, line_C.

i have tried to use sessions to do this:

```
newSub = Subtitles()
newSub.file = request.FILES
request.session['new_sub'] = newSub
```

but when i try to request.session.get('new_sub', None), it returns me an error saying object cannot be serialized

also i was thinking of saveing it to the database in the first view and then getting it back from there in the second one but it means i would have to get the pk of the instance at the moment of creating it to be able to access it in the second view. the only way i can think of it how it can be done is to get the last file that was saved to db, is it the only way?

since the file is a .txt i can also read its content in the first view and and put it as a string into the reqest.session but it seems not right

what is the proper way o approach this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine your solutions. Save it to the db in the first view, the add the pk to the session, and in the second view get the pk from the session and load the object from the database.